# Minified css and java-script files

Tags: asp.net

I looked for some extension that will minify my js and css files at runtime and ran across

[Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/)

what I did:

- I have download it and installed it.
- created a config file in the CSS folder, called Bundel.chirp.config

[image]

- this is the config file content:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <root xmlns="urn:ChirpyConfig"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ChirpyConfig http://www.weirdlover.com/chirpy/chirp.xsd">
  <FileGroup Name="site.css">
    <File Path="imgeffect.css" Minify="false" />
    <File Path="magnific-popup.css" />
    <File Path="prettyCheckable.css" Minify="false" />
    <File Path="style.css" />
  </FileGroup>
  ```

**Nothing has changed if i look in the developer tools on the CSS files:**
[image]

**I forgot something?**

Comment: This functionality is built in, it's known ad [Bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: Already been at this page, what does I have to add to my code?

Comment: There is a link on that page. If you're using Web Forms go to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx